# Why doesn't display none work in print media query?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have got a website which needs to be printed without any headers, footers or backgrounds visible. For the footer and container backgrounds this works fine, I cannot figure out how to hide my header container however.

My HTML:

```
<div id=header>
    <div id=logoContainer>
          <a href="mainPage.php"><img id=logo src="xxx.png"></img></a>
      <div id=pageTitle>
        <h1 id=pageTitleText>TITLE</h1>
      </div>
      <div id=headerUserInfo>
        <span>Logged in as: <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?> | </span><a class=logout href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
height:90px;
background:url("images/header.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #2d3133;}

@media print {
      #header {
        display: none !important;
      }
}
```

When opening the Chrome inspector and selecting the header container the @media print rules are not showing up for the header at all. (Rendering is set to emulate print in Chrome.) Footer and other containers work fine, its just the header.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: A working example:

HTML:

```
<div id="tableContainer">

  <div class="buttonsDiv">
    <a href="new.php" class="mainButton">Button 1</a>
    <a class="mainButton">Button 2</a>
    <a class="mainButton">Button 3/a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
      #header {
        display: none !important;
      }
      #footer {
        display: none;
      }
      #tableContainer {
        background: transparent !important;
      }
```

Comment: Can you show the html and css for a container that works? It's important to compare them since one works and the other does not

Comment: I edited the main post.

Comment: Ok, assuming footer works fine, then from the posted code, I don't see any issues other than the quotes but you said you added them. Maybe you have spelling mistakes in your actual code css or html? Have you tried printing it out and see if the header appears?

Comment: Just printed it, header appears. Everything else looks like I want it to look. I do not really how I would have any spelling mistakes in the couple of words responsible for this…

Comment: Well, if you spelled header wrong in css or html, this will break. Do this: check the css file for print in chrome. You should be able to see the rule for header. Make sure it is there and correct. I don't mean inspect but I mean the actual css output file

Comment: I have no idea why is did not work, but I just made a new class and used that instead of the header id and it works perfectly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use `"` in defining id `<div id="header">`

```css
#header {
height:90px;
background:url("images/header.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #2d3133;}

@media print {
      #header {
        display: none !important;
      }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id=logoContainer>
          <a href="mainPage.php"><img id=logo src="xxx.png"></img></a>
      <div id=pageTitle>
        <h1 id=pageTitleText>TITLE</h1>
      </div>
      <div id=headerUserInfo>
        <span>Logged in as: <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?> | </span><a class=logout href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help. Here are two screenshots from the inspector. As you can see the rules for the header container are still not visible: http://imgur.com/a/wST6d

Comment: You don't think maybe the same should have been done for all the other elements? (The truth, though, is that it doesn't *have* to be done for any of them. This is not XHTML.)

Comment: @ppgcc74: The quotes don't make any difference. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @BoltClock i dont see any other issues other than this. that why i suggested this as it might be some what browser sensitive code

Comment: That's why I'm telling you now that it's *not* an issue, and there is nothing browser sensitive about it. But even if you thought it *was* an issue, the least you could do was be consistent. Right now it just seems like you're not even sure yourself if you know what you're talking about.

Comment: yaah. I can realize it. but wanted to help. sorry not other than that